# How can I see a pcap generated with "Shark for root" on my computer?

Tags: android, ftp, wireshark

I rooted my Android phone, and installed "Shark for Root".
Then dumped a file with like 1 minute worth of traffic.

I can see the file on my Android device with Shark Reader. I can see it in "Yaffs Explorer".

But when I try to copy (share via email, upload to ftp, via the Windows Explorer), it doesn't work or doesn't show.
Doesn't work meaning:
FTP says "upload failed, transfer failed".
Share via email says "Cannot read attachment".

So looks to be some kind of permission problem, but in Yaffs explorer the permissions are -rw-rw-r-. So should be fine... But in Windows Explorer, I can't see it.

I even tried zipping the file via Yaffs Explorer, but even this zip file I can't see.

Is there anyone who knows how to copy this pcap file onto my computer so I can load it up in Wireshark?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could not see them either on Windows File Explorer. When I checked with ES File Explorer there were pcap files. So, I simply put a dummy extension to the file (for example, shark_dump_12345.pcap to shark_dump_12345.pcap.zip using renaming function) and then File Explorer could see the zip file.

I copied that file to the computer and simply removed the ".zip" and opened it with Wireshark. I have no idea why File Explorer did not show pcap files.

Comment: I copied them by rebooting the phone. Then I could see these files! Strange but true...